# Remove specific image from array with tripple tap gesture

Tags: ios, xcode

When the user presserà on a button, a UIImageView is created (image1) and added in an NSMutable called array3. I can move the images on the screen, but the user must be' able to delete a particular image, so I added a trippletap gesture. The gesture is working fine, but, when I trippletap, all of the images are removed, or only the last one:

Only the last one:

```
[image1 removeFromSuperview];
```

All of them:

```
For (UIImageView *image in array3){ [image removeFromSuperview]; }
```

I can't seem to get only the tapped on image to be' deleted

To detect the gesture I added this under touchesbegan:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
NSUInteger tapCount = [touch tapCount];
Switch (tapCount) {
case3:
[self trippleTap];
Break;
```

Above the case 3 I added case 1 and two...

Then...

```
-(void)trippleTouch{    [image1 removeFromSuperview];}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the tap gesture event handling? Or how do you "detect" the tap?

Comment: As u said that u are able to move images on screen; are you using the same UIImageView to display multiple images? If yes then you cant remove that UIImageView(image1) from superview. It wont show you images anymore. If you are using different UIImageView to display diff images. then put some code to solve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately I am posting with iPad so I am having troubled formattino the codes, but,no, the images are displayed in different UIImageViews added proprammly. All of them are gives the same name when allocated (image1) and added to the array